# VBA Pastespecial range

Tags: vba, excel

This is a little embarrassing as I just posted a related questions for copying ranges, but the problem I faced is that my last approached did not allow for paste special.

Now I try to copy from sheet to the other and I get an error. The baseline code is from a sheet where it works without problems, but here it produces a `1004 error` pointing the the first set line.

```
Sub Script()
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Row = Worksheets("Design").Cells(11, 22).Value
Col = Worksheets("Design").Cells(12, 22).Value

  Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Cells(2 + 19 * Row, 1 + 19 * Col), Cells(19 + 19 * Row, 18 + Col * 19))
  Set varRangeSelect2 = Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(18, 18))
  varRangeselect1.Copy
  varRangeSelect2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Worksheets("Tablecorrected")` before the `cells` like you did with `range`.

Answer (score 1):

Findwindow gave the right hint, the working code is:

```
Sub Script()
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Row = Worksheets("Design").Cells(11, 22).Value
Col = Worksheets("Design").Cells(12, 22).Value

  Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Cells(2 + 19 * Row, 1 + 19 * Col), Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Cells(19 + 19 * Row, 18 + Col * 19))
  Set varRangeSelect2 = Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Range(Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Cells(18, 18))
  varRangeselect1.Copy
  varRangeSelect2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

thanks !